# Rails 3 - form_for pluralization causing path/method error on "new" action but not on "edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, form-for, pluralize

When I go to the path:  `/genre/new` in my application I get this error:

```
myapp/app/views/genre/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `genres_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdcb39edcb0>:0x007fdcb39e8080>
```

However when I go to /genre/:id/edit the _form.html.erb file renders without error and the record is updated with no problems.

My `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` files call `<%= render 'form' %>` and my `_form.html.erb` file has:

```
<%= form_for(@genre) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %> <br />  <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.label :desc %>  <br />  <%= f.text_field :desc %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In genre_controller.rb my 'new' and 'edit' actions are as follows:

```
  def new
    @genre = Genre.new
    current_user.authorize! :create, @genre  # cancan authorization

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @genre }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @genre = Genre.find(params[:id])
    current_user.authorize! :update, @genre   # cancan authorization
  end
```

I've run a search in my codebase for the string "genres" and the only place it occurs is in the logs, so I'm sure this is not a typo in my code.

My guess is that Rails routing system correctly pluralizes "genre" to "genre", but form_for (or a dependency) is creating the pluralization "genres", but only when the parameter passed to it is empty or "new".

Given the error is around 'genres_path', I tried various combinations of the following in my routes.rb file, but they didn't solve the problem:

```
  match "/genres" => "genre#index", :as => :genre
  match "/genres/:id(.:format)" => "genre#show", :as => :genre
  match "/genre" => "genre#index", :as => :genres
  match "/genre/:id(.:format)" => "genre#show", :as => :genres
```

Any thoughts on how I can work around this?

EDIT: Here are the routes generated by the `resources :genre` statement in my `routes.rb` file:

```
genre_index GET    /genre(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"genre"}
            POST   /genre(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"genre"}
  new_genre GET    /genre/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"genre"}
 edit_genre GET    /genre/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"genre"}
      genre GET    /genre/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"genre"}
            PUT    /genre/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"genre"}
            DELETE /genre/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"genre"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on new.html.erb try

```
<%= form_for(@genre, :url => genre_path, :method => :post) do |f| %>
```

assuming you have your route setup as a resource - `resources :genre`

also this will not work on edit.html.erb

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

**Update:**

this is the one we are interested in

```
POST   /genre(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"genre"}
```

try this

```
<%= form_for(@genre, :url => {:action=>"create", :controller=>"genre"}, :method => :post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I tried it and it leads to a different error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"genre"}.  But this is a bogus error - I have a route like that. When I run "rake routes" I get:  genre GET  /genre/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"genre"}  The exact route the error message say's I'm missing.  Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: can you add the output from rake routes for all of the genre routes - also see updated answer - specify the method as put or post

Comment: See my routes in the question, at the bottom.  Tried both :put and :post as :methods - same error as before ("no route matches...")  Also, tried a few things I saw in the docs, but no success.  This really has me stumped.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried your last set of arguments for form_for with no success.  Looking at multiple dictionaries, I've seen that "genres" is an acceptable pluralization.  So I decided not to fight Rails on this issue.  I went back and changed the names of my controller, helper, and db table, as well as some link_to statements.  It all works now.  I guess the moral of the story is: never fight Rails on pluralization - you will loose in the end.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I had a similar problem that had nothing to do with plurals.  I was using a non-namespaced model class (Book) with a namespaced (Admin) controller, so the resource based route is declared as "namespace :admin do resources :books end".  The correct path for the index named route is then "admin_books_path".  However, as explained in the link provided in this answer, form_for(@book) will take the path to be just "books_path", so I had to override the :url, writing  "form_for(@book, :url => admin_books_path)", to get things to work.